# Can I make my USB flash drive traceable?

Tags: usb, internet

I'd like to be able to track my USB flash drive in the event of it being lost. For example if I lost it it would alert me immediately when it s plugged into a device that has an internet connection. Is this possible? If so, how can I make this work. Thanks in advance for any help given!

Comment: No, it's a storage device,  It simply doesn't have the smarts to do anything else.  Additionally the PC host only uses it as a storage device. Letting a USB device do anything other than its intended function sounds like opening a Pandora box, i.e. a security risk.  BTW fix your title.  "USB" without specifying a device is something else (i.e. the bus itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need some way to make a hidden program on the USB drive launch itself automatically on the target system, bypassing any OS and anti-malware security measures against autorun type programs, then get it to connect successfully to the internet bypassing firewalls and the like. Short of some sort of really *really* sophisticated cross-platform Stuxnet/Flame-type malware I don't see how all this is possible.

Comment: Lojack for flash drives, lol.

Comment: It is, if you are willing to :)